# How do I solve $y''=(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

y''=(y')^2  can anyone help to for this math thank

Comment: Can you solve $y'=y^2$?

Comment: It's better to add your attempts and where you're stuck.

Comment: Still missing is the variant where you set $y'=u(y)$, $y''=uu'$, so that you get $u'=u\implies u=Ce^y$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$y''=(y')^2$$
Note that $y=c$ is a solution.
Rewrite it as:
$$\dfrac {y''}{y'}=y'$$
$$(\ln y')'=y'$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\left(\frac{1}{y'}\right)' =-\frac{y''}{(y' )^2 }$$

using the above identity we can write your equation as

$$\left(\frac{1}{y'}\right)' =-1 $$

Therefore $$\frac{1}{y'} =-x+C$$ and hence

$$y=-\ln|-x+C|+D$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $y'' = (y')^{2}$ is equivalent to $z' = z^{2}$, where $y$ is an antiderivative of $z$. Then, by separation of variables:

$\frac{dz}{dx} = z^{2}$

$\frac{dz}{z^{2}} = dx$

Integrating both sides:

$-\frac{1}{z} + C_{1} = x + C_{2}$

$z = -\frac{1}{x + C_{3}}$

Then, because $y = \int z dz$:

$y = -\ln(x + C_{3}) + C_{4}$

Using log rules:

$\boxed{y = \ln(\frac{C_{4}}{x + C_{3}})}$